# Restore deleted links from left navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have deleted few links from the current navigation by clicking on `edit links` and then clicking on `cross sign`.

I need the same navigation to restore there but i dont remember the links and their title.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is no way I know of to recover deleted navigation links, outside chance of clicking back in your browser a couple times to see if they are there in history

Comment: I do also think that user cannot restore deleted navigation links as they aren't content so that they are sent to recycle bin or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Eric is correct, the links are not moved to the recycle bin.

If you need to rebuild the links, you might want to look into doing a restore to another site collection, then use the visual queue to rebuild the links.

Answer (score 0):

The steps listed by Ganesh and zszsz are correct for the default navigation links. Note that "Choose an option" is a drop down menu that allows you to choose any of the group-connected app links.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to `Edit` at the end of the list.
2. Click the `PLUS`, see the `Add a Link` pop-up.
3. Under `Choose an option`,
   Instead of URL, you can select any of the missing default items.